# Unity Random.Range Issue

Tags: c#, game-development

I have a script where it will generate buttons onto a canvas, by Duplicating the Button and assign a random value to the x and y. But the Random.Range is giving values outside of the Minium and maximum. Is there any way to fix this? Script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject spawnButtonPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Transform Canvas;
    [Range(0f, 15f)]
    [SerializeField] private float WaitTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("Spawn");
    }
    IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime);
        GameObject Object = Instantiate(spawnButtonPrefab, Canvas);
        Vector2 Position = Vector2.zero;
        Position.x = Random.Range(-550f, 550f);
        Position.y = Random.Range(-250f, 250f);

        Object.transform.position = Position;
        yield return StartCoroutine("Spawn");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the values it's returning? Are you sure it's happening *immediately* rather than something else modifying the `Vector2`? (I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, at least for the local variables. It's very odd to see PascalCase used for them... And I'd recommend against calling anything `Object` too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It is giving values like 889 -720 and rarely it would be in the min and max range

Comment: Again: are you sure that's happening *immediately*? Do you see that in the debugger before you use `Position` for anything else? (It does feel unlikely that such a widely-used method would be so badly broken...)

Comment: I just found the problem. For some reason I had to change ```Object.positon ```to ```Object.rectTransform.position```. I'm not sure how this fixed it, but I think when I assign the parent to the canvas, the canvas tries to convert the ```transform.positon``` to ```rectTransform.positon```.

Comment: And that sort of thing is precisely why I encouraged you to look at `Position` *immediately* after construction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. For some reason I had to change Object.positon to Object.rectTransform.position. I'm not sure how this fixed it, but I think when I assign the parent to the canvas, the canvas tries to convert the transform.positon to rectTransform.positon.